# Laravel Backpack Create/Update action that customize the foreign field

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want the "Unit" field that saved to my model is not the default field (`id`), but instead customized field (e.g.: I want to save the Unit field with `name` from the foreign table, not the `id`)

[image]

How to do that? currently why CrudController is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there’s a 1-to-1 relationship (hasOne) defined in your model, you should be able to do that by giving the field the name “unit.name”.

Comment: is this what you mean, the 1-1 relationship in the model?

public function itemUnit() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\ItemUnit::class);
}

Comment: oh wait, do you when 'name' => 'unit.name' ? in the crud field?